# Migrate Kohana from Apache to NginX

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, kohana

I'm migrating a Kohana App version 3.0.4 from Apache to NginX.
I'm getting troubles with the configuration .htaccess. On NginX work correctly only the internal URL's like:

```
 http://myurlwithoutwww.net.ds/internalpage/anotherpage
```

but nether the homepage

```
 http://myurlwithoutwww.net.ds/
```

nether this:

```
 http://myurlwithoutwww.net.ds/index.php
```

works. The last two will simply display a blank screen.

this is the htaccess file from where I'm trying to migrate:

```
    AddType text/x-component .htc
#Accept-Encoding: filter,deflate
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9\-]+).([a-z]{2,3})$       [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1         [L,R=301]

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

#   ExpiresActive On
#   <FilesMatch \.(bmp|png|gif|jpe?g|html?|ico|doc|swf)$>
#        ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
#   </FilesMatch>

FileETag none

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^async/?(.*)?                   index.php?dispatcher=async&$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(?:_application|_modules|_system)\b index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php?kohana_uri=$0 [PT,L,QSA]
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

And this my current Nginx configuration:

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
   include /etc/nginx/aliases.conf;
   root   /var/www/webroot/ROOT;
   index  index.php;

   location / {
   expires off;
       try_files $uri $uri/ @kohana;
   }

   # Prevent access to hidden files
   location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
   }

   location @kohana {
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php$request_uri last;
   }

   location ~* \.php {

            #location ~ /\. { deny all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/webroot/ROOT/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param KOHANA_ENV development;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/webroot/ROOT;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below config, also check bootstrap init if it has 'index_file' => FALSE.

```
    server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *.domain.com;

    client_max_body_size 20M;

    access_log /home/user/public_html/site/log/access.log;
    error_log  /home/user/public_html/site/log/error.log;

    root       /home/user/public_html/site/public/;
    index      index.php;

    location / {
                # don’t check $uri/, send to php for nice error message
                try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /index.php {
        include       fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty old question, but maybe you will find it useful, the way I do:

```
location / {
index  index.html index.htm index.php;
try_files  $uri index.php;
}

location /kohana {

rewrite ^(.+)$ /kohana/index.php?kohana_uri=$1 last;
if (-f $request_filename) {

                    break;
            }
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^/kohana/(.+)$ /kohana/index.php?kohana_uri=$1 last;
            }
}
```

I just listed the main sections of default.conf.

Comment: In `nginx`, [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) — isn't there a way to just use `try_files` combined with `rewrite`?